# Guaranteed bounds for key press times in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, keyboard

Here is basically how I get some "key speed typing data" with JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input id="in"></input>
<p id="out">new</p>
<script>
var downlast = 0;
document.getElementById("in").onkeydown = function () {
    var downlast2 = new Date().getTime();
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML += ","+(downlast2-downlast);
    downlast = downlast2;
};
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

But, at times the CPU is busy, delaying event triggers, causing errors of even more than 50ms.
So, is there a way to modify this script to catch and void most of these outliers?  I hoped to find minimum/maximum bounds on the key press times, but this now seems impossible with
JavaScript's event-driven methods (i.e., instead of events, I'd prefer to have a function to check
if a key is currently pressed).

Most generally, I am looking for any solution which will work in a Chrome browser, so I don't
actually need to stick with Javascript.  How can I collect typing data with more
confidence if I can't control how busy the client's CPU is?

Comment: are you trying to measure how long it takes to press a key? or are you trying to provide words per minute calculations?

Comment: I am trying to measure time difference between two keys as a function of which specific two keys.  For example, "if" might usually be faster than "in".

Comment: i think the short answer is likely to be “javascript is the wrong tool for this” since as you’ve already noted, all execution is scheduled on an event loop, and you have no way to guarantee when your execution will start.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure and thus asked the question. If someone makes that an answer, and recommends a specific method, I'd accept it.  It's even fine to say that I would need to install an OS-specific app (e.g., a Windows app), but I'm still hoping for a solution which works within Chrome, like writing a Chrome app/plugin/extension, or a Java applet (discontinued?), or an Adobe Flash game, or any other candidates.  To generalize more, it's just hard for me to believe that all "realtime clock guarantees" are impossible within browsers.

Comment: all good. i posted the reply as an answer. i’m sorry i don’t have a recommendation for you, but javascript wasn’t designed to do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because all execution in javascript is scheduled on an event loop, it can’t get you accurate measurements of how long between the user presses buttons, since those signals have to get scheduled between whatever other javascript is running on the page.

I don’t have a recommendation for how to do this in the browser.

Comment: Let me also add that browsers don't want to give out very precise timing details (or CPU activity level details) because it opens themselves up to security "timing attacks".